# Как внедрить в сервис-контейнер объект с постами из БД?

Tags: php, laravel, сервисы

Необходимо в контроллере,имея переменную city, простым вызовом

```
$city='1';
$posts=app('posts')->posts;
```

получить объект выборки из БД вот такой(заметьте, что здесь фигурирует переменная $city):

```
$posts = DB::table('post')->where('city', $city)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Как это реализовать через сервисконтейнер, сервиспровайдер, фасад(если необходимо)?

Comment: Это __плохой подход__.

Comment: Почему плохой, если у меня много методов связано с объектом $posts?

Comment: Плохо то что выборка зависит от какой-то переменной, установленной черт знает где. Все переменные, от которых зависит выборка, должны приходить в функцию выборки аргументами.

Comment: Поэтому я и написал здесь вопрос, чтобы вы помогли мне организовать архитектуру такого контейнера. В этом и суть вопроса, куда эту переменную вставлять и как